Incomprehensible symbol in terminal (venv)

In the code editor terminal, when the .venv is running, strange symbols are displayed. This has never happened before. It appeared quite recently.
Attached screenshot.
I use Manjaro Linux with Plasma
And I have no idea what this could be about ...
